# Passing email address via query string in C#

Tags: c#, url

I want to send a URL to a person. This URL needs to include an email address. Basically, I want something that looks like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?e=emailAddress@network.com
```

From my understanding, I cannot pass an email address directly via URL. Rather, I need to encode it first. Am I correct in my understanding? If so, how do I encode it using C#? I see all sorts of encoding options, but I'm not sure what to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it would be a good idea to URL encode an argument, using something like `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`.

However, what you've shown passes an email in a URL query argument. Not sure what you mean about sending a URL to a person.

Comment: And then you need to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` to retrieve given email from the query parameter.

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing it from C#, use [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) to encode something into a url.

From the article:

```
String MyURL;
MyURL = "http://www.contoso.com/articles.aspx?title=" + Server.UrlEncode("ASP.NET Examples");
```

or for your case:

```
String MyURL = "http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?e=" + Server.UrlEncode("emailAddress@network.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using HttpUtility.UrlEncode() for the email-address, this should do what you want.

Comment: The other Chris was faster ;-)